# Unable to reset IPMI cipher using ipmitool: "Parameter Data does not match" – why?

Tags: security, dell, ipmi, ipmitool, bmc

In attempting to make some Dell server BMC's more secure, I followed the recommendations given elsewhere and disabled cipher 0, using the following command (`ipmitool` running on the host OS, which is CentOS 6.5 – I'm root while doing this, of course):

```
> ipmitool lan set 1 cipher_privs XXXaXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then I wanted to change it to something else, and discovered that, apparently, I can't:

```
> ipmitool lan set 1 cipher_privs Xaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
LAN Parameter Data does not match!  Write may have failed.
```

In other respects, things look fine:

```
> ipmitool lan print 1
Set in Progress         : Set In Progress
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD5
                        : User     : MD5
                        : Operator : MD5
                        : Admin    : MD5
                        : OEM      :
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : ...omitted for this posting...
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.255.0
MAC Address             : ...omitted for this posting...
SNMP Community String   : ...omitted for this posting...
IP Header               : TTL=0x40 Flags=0x40 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x10
Default Gateway IP      : ...omitted for this posting...
Default Gateway MAC     : 00:00:00:00:00:00
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
Backup Gateway MAC      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
802.1q VLAN ID          : Disabled
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
RMCP+ Cipher Suites     : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : XXXaXXXXXXXXXXX
                        :     X=Cipher Suite Unused
                        :     c=CALLBACK
                        :     u=USER
                        :     o=OPERATOR
                        :     a=ADMIN
                        :     O=OEM
```

Does anyone recognize this problem, and know how to solve it?  Why does it appear impossible now to change the `cipher_privs` value?  I'm probably doing something ignorant – apologies if so.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the configuration on the idrac. Ssh to the idrac, run racadm, then run resetconfig. When it comes back up, the cipher settings will be default.